# performance issue while binding gridview with huge data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Problem: i am trying to fetch huge number of entries from the database and binding it to the gridview which is making my site performance very low.
what i have used: i have indexed the parameters which are mainly involved while searching. Also i am stroing the database returned queries in session and using it while paging, instead of hitting the database again.

What i want? is there any way we can just retrieve entries from the database for the page size of the grid. my grid page size is 10. So 10 entries would higly enhance the performance of the site. Since there are numerous fields in the datagrid and fetching them takes time. So is there any solution like this?

code for the query:

```
R1.DBLinqRDataContext objDB = new R1.DBLinqRDataContext();
return ( from p in (from a in objDB.table1
        orderby a.date descending
        join i in objDB.table2
        on a.ID equals i.ID
                    where ((SqlMethods.Like(a.Location, "%" + loc + "%")) && (Category != String.Empty ? (Category == "1" ? a.Func < 50 : a.Func > 50) : (SqlMethods.Like(a.loc, "%" + loc + "%"))))
        select a) join r3 in objDB.table3 on p.ID equals r3.CompanyID select p).Distinct().ToList();
```

Any assist?

if any more details please ask....thank you

Comment: check out this article on [SQL Paging](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/070628.htm). I've done something similar in stored procs, but you should be able to tailor it to linq

Comment: Thanks prescott...
i have edited my query in this way
after distinct i added the following code:
.Skip((pageIndex) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList()
but my pgaing list is also gone i just see 10 entries and not able to navigate

Comment: Ah yes - [Improve GridView Performance by Delegating Paging to SQL Server](http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=23) shows you how to do this for sql stored procs, if you just adapt this for your linq code it will do what you need. It's a bit more involved, but it will give you a nice framework for future work you need to do with paging

Comment: Did you profile and see which part of you application is slow? Is it getting from database or loading data in the gridview. I suspect it might be gridview, because if you bind lot of data to the grid view, it will create a UIlement for each cell and that will slow down loading, Did you try to enable virtualization in GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the other answer's point, doing a [query].Skip(x).Take(y) works great, but check when you make the skip and take calls that you're calling the IQueriable version and not the IEnumerable version.

If you call the IQueriable version then it gets incorporated into the query.  IEnumerable will execute the query and then run the paging in memory and you loose all your performance gains.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading through [this](http://borrell.parivedasolutions.com/2008/01/objectdatasource-linq-paging-sorting.html)